# fzf tmux pasteb deleteb

Tags: bash, tmux, fzf

Trying to understand where `pasteb` and `deleteb` is coming from?

I expected that if I open tmux manually that pasteb and deleteb are build in commands or something but they aren't as far as I can tell if try to type them in a tmux session?

https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.bash#L34

```
__fzf_select_tmux__() {
  local height
  height=${FZF_TMUX_HEIGHT:-40%}
  if [[ $height =~ %$ ]]; then
    height="-p ${height%\%}"
  else
    height="-l $height"
  fi

  tmux split-window $height "cd $(printf %q "$PWD"); FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS=$(printf %q "$FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS") PATH=$(printf %q "$PATH") FZF_CTRL_T_COMMAND=$(printf %q "$FZF_CTRL_T_COMMAND") FZF_CTRL_T_OPTS=$(printf %q "$FZF_CTRL_T_OPTS") bash -c 'source \"${BASH_SOURCE[0]}\"; RESULT=\"\$(__fzf_select__ --no-height)\"; tmux setb -b fzf \"\$RESULT\" \\; pasteb -b fzf -t $TMUX_PANE \\; deleteb -b fzf || tmux send-keys -t $TMUX_PANE \"\$RESULT\"'"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are internal tmux commands.

From `tmux` [man page](https://man.cx/tmux) :

> delete-buffer [−b buffer-name]
>
> (alias: deleteb)
>
> Delete the buffer named buffer-name, or the most recently added automatically named buffer if not specified.

---

> paste-buffer [−dpr] [−b buffer-name] [−s separator] [−t target-pane]
>
> (alias: pasteb)
>
> Insert the contents of a paste buffer into the specified pane. If not specified, paste into the current one. With −d, also delete the paste buffer. When output, any linefeed (LF) characters in the paste buffer are replaced with a separator, by default carriage return (CR). A custom separator may be specified using the −s flag. The −r flag means to do no replacement (equivalent to a separator of LF). If −p is specified, paste bracket control codes are inserted around the buffer if the application has requested bracketed paste mode.

Comment: Ok thx but should the bash script not be ...`tmux deleteb`... then? In the script it just `deleteb` as it was a cmd or am i wrong?

Comment: @GertCuykens nope, in this cas the `;` are escaped, so the whole command `setb -b fzf \"\$RESULT\" \\; pasteb -b fzf -t $TMUX_PANE \\; deleteb -b fzf` is passed to tmux